# How do I create a Python pypi package with a C library?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, buildout, pypi

I would like to put the [IP2Location Python library](http://www.ip2location.com/developers/python) on a local Pypi / Cheeseshop server that I have running, so that I can use buildout to automatically include it in a project.

First, I tested out the library by installing it the way that is explained in IP2Location's (terse) documentation: 1) Download the [IP2Location C library](http://www.ip2location.com/developers/c) and compile it 2) Run `python setup.py build && python setup.py install` in the IP2Location Python library.

I got that working, so then I tried to upload the Python library to my local pypi server by running:

```
python setup.py register -r local sdist upload -r local
```

It uploaded a package to my local pypi server, but the package only contained the Python part of the library, not the C part. I'd like the C library to also be included and then automatically compiled when a tool like buildout downloads it from my local pypi server.

I'm pretty new to pypi. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, how?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, at least not the way setup.py is structured in the python library.
You might have some luck getting repeatability by trying the following though (note that I have not tried this, IP2Location is a proprietary library):

Build the C library in your buildout by means of [zc.recipe.cmmi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.cmmi/). A section similar to the following should do the job.

```
[iplocationc]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://www.ip2location.com/downloads/ip2location-c-4.0.2.tar.gz
```

Then, install the python counterpart as an egg using [zc.recipe.egg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.egg/1.2.2):

```
[iplocation]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
eggs = iplocation
include-dirs = ${buildout:directory}/parts/iplocationc/includes_dir_goes_here
rpath = ${buildout:directory}/parts/iplocationc/libs_dir_location_goes_here
```

You might have to modify the recipe parameters a bit and probably fiddle with the setup.py but hopefully this should do it.